# Removing double quotes when reading csv file with PYSPARK

Tags: csv, pyspark, double-quotes

Hello I am trying to read a csv file using the logic in pyspark running pyspark3 mode.
The source file is full of double quotes in the header and fields values which i would like to erase either when reading via de spark.read.csv function options or a posteriori treating the dataframe.

My source file is like follows:

[source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzvZZ.png)

The expected output will be:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBeay.png)

Note: I can not solve it via spark-shell because there is a technical issue in the server does not allow me to read files.

The best I could do using the sparkreadcsv function options was :
[output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzVVP.png)

Code tried so far:

```
df = spark.read.option('inferSchema',True)\
 .option('header',True)\
.option('sep',';')\
 .option('quote','')\
 .csv('Project 1_dataset_bank-full.csv')
```

I tried to apply some replace functions on the dataframe but also did not succeed:
[replace option1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOeiF.png)

[replace option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVXtU.png)

Comment: The functions your using are not defined. Did you forget to import them at the start of your code? E.g.:

    from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace